# Ubuntu Maverick wont work with my external speakers

Tags: ubuntu-10.10

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Ubuntu Maverick wont work with my external speakers](https://superuser.com/questions/261093/ubuntu-maverick-wont-work-with-my-external-speakers)

Hello guys. I've installed Ubuntu Maverick in my laptop and everything works great. I can hear sounds and everything, but when I connect headphones or external spakers nothing happens. Music keeps coming out of the laptop speakers and nothing comes out of the connected device.

I've already checked Sound Preferences and tried all the "Devices" and nothing seems to be working. What could I do?

Comment: Duplicate of http://superuser.com/questions/261093/ubuntu-maverick-wont-work-with-my-external-speakers also migrated but from stackoverflow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know which is your laptop but this works on Toshiba Satellite and others.

Problem: Built-in speakers work. Plugging in headphones do not mute speakers.

Audio: Conexant CX20585

Solution:

edit:

```
/etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf
```

to add:

```
options snd-hda-intel model=thinkpad
```

Comment: Thansk! Worked!

Answer (score 0):

Open up a terminal with Ctrl-Alt-t and type `alsamixer` and hit enter. Use the arrow keys to move the red highlighting to any channel than has `MM` at the bottom and hit the m key to unmute it. If any channels (such as "Headphones" or "Speakers") are not at 100% volume, you can change this with the up and down arrow keys.  Press escape to quit.