# Ubuntu Maverick wont work with my external speakers

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-10.10

My laptop is running Ubuntu Maverick and sounds works great, but when I connect headphones or external speakers, nothing changes. Sounds keeps coming out just from the laptop speakers. I?ve tried all the devices in the "Sound Preferences" and still nothing. How can I solve this?

My Audio card is:

```
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) HD Audio Controller (rev 03)
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know which is your laptop but this works on Toshiba Satellite and others.

Problem: Built-in speakers work. Plugging in headphones do not mute speakers.

Audio: Conexant CX20585

Solution:

edit:
`/etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf`
to add:

`options snd-hda-intel model=thinkpad`

Comment: Nice this helps :)